# Install Agent To Client Machines

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, nagios

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows, Linux and Mac OS X clients.

I want to install a Nagios agent to our client machines, but I don't know how to do that. Any recommendations?

Comment: What agent? What is that?

Comment: @DanielCasserly Just executable file. (Nagios agent)

Comment: @JeremyMcGee I asked on Microsoft Server Forum but i did not get the answer. I thought i get some programatical way in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Windows Solution

For Windows, you can use Group Policy Software installation to do this. It is very well documented, so I won't rehash the steps here. I'm assuming that you're using NSClient++. It installs nicely, but with the default config file. To work around this, you can do one of the following:

**AIP**
Break apart the .MSI file with `msiexec /a` and edit the default config file for your environment.

**Update the config file with Group Policy**
You can use Group Policy Preferences to update nsc.ini with a known good file from a network share. You will need to either restart the service after, somehow, or wait for the user to reboot their machine for the changes in the file to take effect. I suggest option 1.

---

### Linux/OS X Solution

There are a multitude of configuration management applications for *nix. Chef, Puppet, radmind all come to mind as big ones. If you don't have one of these set up, it's going to be a lot of work to do just to push the one application out. I'd still consider setting one of these up anyway, so that you can take care of future global configuration issues with ease. The premise for how to actually do this is the same as I mentioned for Windows, but will obviously need to be customized to fit whatever option you choose to implement.

---

**tl;dr**
If you don't already have a configuration management system in place, it's not going to be easy. Get one.

Comment: do you know how to write script for group policy installation?

Comment: @GüngörBasa you don't write a script. You link the .msi using Group Policy Software Installation. If you have an additional question, you should search the site to see if it's already been asked. If it hasn't, then you should ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the file to server and then when user clicks on button or link it will redirect them to the location of the file on the server which will start to download it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly i have to do that automaticly. Just system admin push agent to all clients. Just like GOP in Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

For the Windows clients you can, if you have an MSI of the installer, use a Group Policy to push it out.  As for Linux and Mac... you're pretty much going to have to do it manually, I'm afraid.  I'm unaware of any Windows (or other) application that allows you to centrally push an application to multiple client OS's.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a binary storage server that has NSCLient++ MSI hosted and use Chef to download and install it as well as set up the NSCLient.ini file?